# Extrair propriedades de um menu suspenso criado dinamicamente VBA

Tags: vba, menu

Olá, tenho uma rotina que cria menus suspensos dinamicamente, esses menus recebem o caption de um banco de dados (já que dependendo do controle que clico o menu criado recebe outros valores).
Bom, o menu está sendo criado e preenchido corretamente, porém não consigo extrair o caption e outras propriedades desse novo controle, e preciso especificamente do caption do item clicado para poder salvar a ação.

[img][https://i.imgur.com/rSWA9UP.png[/img]](https://i.imgur.com/rSWA9UP.png%5B/img%5D)
Rotina para criar os menus suspenso

```vb
Dim dadosArray() As String
Public obj As Object
Public nomeLocal As String
Public nomeServico As String
Public nomefuncao As String

Sub MenuSuspenso()
    Dim conn As Object
    Dim rs As Object
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim dbPath As String
    Dim rowCount As Long
    Dim colCount As Integer
    Dim i As Long, j As Integer
    Dim menuItemIndex As Integer
    'Dim i As Long
    menuItemIndex = 1
 
    Application.CommandBars("Cell").Reset
    
    Dim cbc As CommandBarControl
    
    ' Oculta todos os comandos do botão direito
    For Each cbc In Application.CommandBars("cell").Controls
        cbc.Visible = False
    Next cbc
    
    ' Caminho do banco de dados
    dbPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\bd\MapaIluminado.accdb"
    
    ' Configurar a conexão ADODB para Access
    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & dbPath & ";Persist Security Info=False;"
    ' Definir quais tabelas acessar
    If InStr(nomeBotao, "btnBloco") > 0 Then
      strSQL = "SELECT servicos FROM tblservicosBlocos"
    ElseIf InStr(nomeBotao, "btnAP") > 0 Then
     strSQL = "SELECT servicos FROM tblServicosPavimentos"
    ElseIf InStr(nomeBotao, "btnPlatibanda") > 0 Then
     strSQL = "SELECT servicos FROM tblServicosPlatibandas"
    End If
    
    ' Consulta SQL para selecionar os dados da tabela
   
    
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    rs.Open strSQL, conn
    
    ' Verificar se há dados
    If Not rs.EOF Then
        ' Obter o número de colunas
        colCount = rs.Fields.Count
        
        ' Inicializar contador de linhas
        rowCount = 0
        
        ' Loop para contar o número de registros e carregar os dados no array
        Do While Not rs.EOF
            rowCount = rowCount + 1
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop
        
        ' Redimensionar o array para armazenar os dados
        ReDim dadosArray(1 To rowCount, 1 To colCount)
        
        ' Voltar ao início do conjunto de resultados
        rs.MoveFirst
        
        ' Colocar os dados no array
        i = 1
        Do While Not rs.EOF
            For j = 1 To colCount
                dadosArray(i, j) = rs.Fields(j - 1).Value
            Next j
            i = i + 1
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop
        
         ' Inserir dados no Menu Suspenso com índices
    Dim indice As Integer
    indice = 1 ' Inicializa o índice
    
    For i = LBound(dadosArray, 1) To UBound(dadosArray, 1)
        For j = LBound(dadosArray, 2) To UBound(dadosArray, 2)
            With Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, Before:=menuItemIndex)
                .Caption = obj.Caption & " - " & "Item " & indice & ": " & dadosArray(i, j)
                .OnAction = **"TESTE" ' AQUI ESTÁ O MEU PROBLEMA - PRECISO DE UMA FUNÇÃO QUE SEJA CHAMA NO ON ACTION**
               
                menuItemIndex = menuItemIndex + 1
                
            End With
            indice = indice + 1 ' Incrementa o índice para o próximo item
        Next j
    Next i
    Else
        MsgBox "Nenhum dado encontrado."
   End If
    
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing
    Application.CommandBars("Cell").ShowPopup
End Sub
```

Answer (score -2):

A propriedade `onAction`, no vba, recebe uma string com o nome da função que deve ser chamada. Portanto, você deve criar uma função e, naquela função, pode descobrir quem está chamando através de `Application.Caller`.

Para descobrir o valor dos seus botões específicos, você pode experimentar um pouco usando `debug.Print`, ou setar o nome (e aí ajusta o `Select` conforme os nomes respectivos).

```vb
Dim dadosArray() As String
' Os valores em dadosArray estão definidos em outra parte do código

Sub MenuSuspenso()
  Dim i As Long, j As Integer
  Dim menuItemIndex As Integer
  menuItemIndex = 1

  Application.CommandBars("Cell").Reset
  
  For i = LBound(dadosArray, 1) To UBound(dadosArray, 1)
      For j = LBound(dadosArray, 2) To UBound(dadosArray, 2)
          With Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, Before:=menuItemIndex)
              .Caption = dadosArray(i, j)
              .OnAction = "MinhaFuncao"
          End With
          menuItemIndex = menuItemIndex + 1
          indice = indice + 1
      Next j
  Next i
  Else
      MsgBox "Nenhum dado encontrado."
  End If
  Application.CommandBars("Cell").ShowPopup
End Sub

Sub MinhaFuncao()
  debug.Print Application.Caller
  Select Case Application.Caller
    Case "button1": MsgBox "Clicked First button"
    Case "button2": AnotherSub 
  End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Caro César Rodrigues, Obrigado pela ajuda, o código postado não funcionou diretamente mas me abriu a mente para conseguir resolver o problema. 
Vou adicionar o Código  abaixo para que alguem possa utiliza-lo, já que não consegui nada sobre esse assunto na net.

Answer (score -2):

Bom consegui Resolver assim:

Código Para criar o menu:

> Dim dadosArray() As String
> Public obj As Object
> Public nomeLocal As String
> Public nomeServico As String
> Public nomefuncao As String

Sub MenuSuspenso()
Dim conn As Object
Dim rs As Object
Dim strSQL As String
Dim dbPath As String
Dim rowCount As Long
Dim colCount As Integer
Dim i As Long, j As Integer
Dim menuItemIndex As Integer
'Dim i As Long
menuItemIndex = 1
Call obter_item_clicado
Application.CommandBars("Cell").Reset

```
Dim cbc As CommandBarControl

' Oculta todos os comandos do botão direito
For Each cbc In Application.CommandBars("cell").Controls
    cbc.Visible = False
Next cbc

' Caminho do banco de dados
dbPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\bd\MapaIluminado.accdb"

' Configurar a conexão ADODB para Access
Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & dbPath & ";Persist Security Info=False;"
' Definir quais tabelas acessar
If InStr(nomeBotao, "btnBloco") > 0 Then
  strSQL = "SELECT servicos FROM tblservicosBlocos"
ElseIf InStr(nomeBotao, "btnAP") > 0 Then
 strSQL = "SELECT servicos FROM tblServicosPavimentos"
ElseIf InStr(nomeBotao, "btnPlatibanda") > 0 Then
 strSQL = "SELECT servicos FROM tblServicosPlatibandas"
End If

' Consulta SQL para selecionar os dados da tabela


Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rs.Open strSQL, conn

' Verificar se há dados
If Not rs.EOF Then
    ' Obter o número de colunas
    colCount = rs.Fields.Count
    
    ' Inicializar contador de linhas
    rowCount = 0
    
    ' Loop para contar o número de registros e carregar os dados no array
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        rowCount = rowCount + 1
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    
    ' Redimensionar o array para armazenar os dados
    ReDim dadosArray(1 To rowCount, 1 To colCount)
    
    ' Voltar ao início do conjunto de resultados
    rs.MoveFirst
    
    ' Colocar os dados no array
    i = 1
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        For j = 1 To colCount
            dadosArray(i, j) = rs.Fields(j - 1).Value
        Next j
        i = i + 1
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    
     ' Inserir dados no Menu Suspenso com índices
Dim indice As Integer

indice = 1 ' Inicializa o índice

For i = LBound(dadosArray, 1) To UBound(dadosArray, 1)
    For j = LBound(dadosArray, 2) To UBound(dadosArray, 2)
        With Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, Before:=menuItemIndex)
            .Caption = obj.Caption & " - " & "Item " & indice & ": " & dadosArray(i, j)
            .OnAction = "PropriedadesMenu" '
           
            menuItemIndex = menuItemIndex + 1
            
        End With
  
        indice = indice + 1 ' Incrementa o índice para o próximo item
        Debug.Print obj.Name & " - " & menuItemIndex
    Next j
Next i
Else
    MsgBox "Nenhum dado encontrado."
```

End If

```
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
conn.Close
Set conn = Nothing
Application.CommandBars("Cell").ShowPopup
```

End Sub

Código para capturar o valor de dentro da Array( que define o caption do objeto criado) ao invés de pegar o valor diretamente do caption) esse foi opulo do gato

```
Sub PropriedadesMenu()
```

Dim botao As CommandBarButton
Set botao = CommandBars.ActionControl ' Obter o botão clicado

```
' Verificar se o botão pertence à barra de ferramentas "Cell"
If botao.Parent.Name = "Cell" Then
    Dim botaoIndex As Integer
    botaoIndex = botao.Index ' Obtém o índice do botão clicado
    
    ' Ajuste para corresponder ao índice correto do array de dados
    Dim indiceDadosArray As Integer
    indiceDadosArray = botaoIndex + LBound(dadosArray, 1) - 1
    
    ' Verifica se o índice está dentro dos limites do array de dados
    If indiceDadosArray >= LBound(dadosArray, 1) And indiceDadosArray <= UBound(dadosArray, 1) Then
        Dim nome As String
        nome = dadosArray(indiceDadosArray, 1)
        
        Debug.Print nome
    Else
        Debug.Print "Índice fora do intervalo do array de dados."
    End If
End If
End Sub
```